# Understanding :source option of has_one/has_many through of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

Please help me in understanding the `:source` option of `has_one/has_many :through` association. The Rails API explanation makes very little sense to me.

> "Specifies the source association name used by `has_many` `:through =>
>   :queries`. Only use it if the name cannot be inferred from the
>   association. `has_many :subscribers, :through => :subscriptions` will
>   look for either `:subscribers` or `:subscriber` on `Subscription`,
>   unless a `:source` is given. "

Answer (score 282, accepted):

Sometimes, you want to use different names for different associations. If the name you want to use for an association on the model isn't the same as the assocation on the `:through` model, you can use `:source` to specify it.

I don't think the above paragraph is *much* clearer than the one in the docs, so here's an example. Let's assume we have three models, `Pet`, `Dog` and `Dog::Breed`.

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
end

class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pet
  has_many :breeds
end

class Dog::Breed < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dog
end
```

In this case, we've chosen to namespace the `Dog::Breed`, because we want to access `Dog.find(123).breeds` as a nice and convenient association.

Now, if we now want to create a `has_many :dog_breeds, :through => :dogs` association on `Pet`, we suddenly have a problem. Rails won't be able to find a `:dog_breeds` association on `Dog`, so Rails can't possibly know *which* `Dog` association you want to use. Enter `:source`:

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
  has_many :dog_breeds, :through => :dogs, :source => :breeds
end
```

With `:source`, we're telling Rails to **look for an association called `:breeds` on the `Dog` model** (as that's the model used for `:dogs`), and use that.

Comment: I think you meant for your last class Animal to be called class Pet, just a typo I believe.

Comment: In the example above, should the the association under `Dog` be `has_many :breed` instead of `:breeds` and then the `:source` be `:breed` singular, to represent the model name, instead of `:breeds` which represents the table name? E.g. `has_many :dog_breeds, :through => :dogs, :source => :breed` (no `s` suffixing `:breed`)?

Comment: I've tested this. it is singular, no `s` suffix in the `:source =>`

Comment: "In this case, we've chosen to namespace the Dog::Breed, because we want to access Dog.find(123).breeds as a nice and convenient association.". You don't need a namespace for that do you?

Answer (score 230):

Let me expand on that example:

```
class User
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :newsletters, :through => :subscriptions
end

class Newsletter
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions
end

class Subscription
  belongs_to :newsletter
  belongs_to :user
end
```

With this code, you can do something like `Newsletter.find(id).users` to get a list of the newsletter's subscribers. But if you want to be clearer and be able to type `Newsletter.find(id).subscribers` instead, you must change the Newsletter class to this:

```
class Newsletter
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :subscribers, :through => :subscriptions, :source => :user
end
```

You are renaming the `users` association to `subscribers`. If you don't provide the `:source`, Rails will look for an association called `subscriber` in the Subscription class. You have to tell it to use the `user` association in the Subscription class to make the list of subscribers.

Comment: note that, the singularize model names should be used in `:source =>`, not plural. So, `:users` is wrong, `:user` is correct

Comment: This is the best answer!, let me just emphasize this part: "You are renaming the users association to subscribers. If you don't provide the :source, Rails will look for an association called subscriber in the Subscription class."

Answer (score 19):

Most simple answer:

Is the name of the relationship in the table in the middle.