# Need help to understand :source_type option of has_one/has_many through of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 3.1, the documentation says

"4.2.2.13 :source_type

The :source_type option specifies the source association type for a has_one :through association that proceeds through a polymorphic association.
"

I just read [:source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632408/need-help-to-understand-source-option-of-has-one-has-many-through-of-rails) explanation but still dont get what source_type is used for?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`:source_type` deals with associations that are polymorphic.  That is to say, if you have a relationship like this:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :books, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => "Book"
  has_many :movies, :through => :taggings, :source => :taggable, :source_type => "Movie"
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end
```

Then the source type allows you to make queries like this:

"Find me all of the books that have been tagged with the tag named 'Fun'"

```
tag = tag.find_by_name('Fun')
tag.books
```

Without source type, you wouldn't be able to do that, you could only get a collection of objects that were tagged with 'Fun'.  If you only specificed source, it wouldn't know which kind of class the objects were, so you it wouldn't know which table in the DB to pull from.  The `source_type` Informs it of which type of object you are trying to retreive.

This is taken from this blog post:  http://www.brentmc79.com/posts/polymorphic-many-to-many-associations-in-rails

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a good explanation. Would you be able to submit a patch to the docrails project explaining it in the same way? http://github.com/lifo/docrails.

Comment: Thanks! I've been searching for this for a long time!

Comment: You mean that it wouldn't know which kind of class for a join in a relation.  It would figure out the type of class from `taggings.map {|link| link.taggable}`

Comment: then how to find all the taggable from a tag?, should I fetch it manually from tagging?

Answer (score 8):

**☝ this message is about the post above** 
(I don't have enough reputation yet to add this as comment...)

Thanks [@TheDelChop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/303675/thedelchop) for that simple and perfect use case. I just propose to complete your perfect explanation with this simple schema which describe your user story. Just in case of.
Thank you !
[image]

Comment: This illustration would be better incorporated into the previous answer.