# rationale for :source in has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm reading Service Oriented Design with Ruby on Rails, which includes the code you see in this image

[image]

My question is specifically about this line from the User model

```
has_many :followers, :through -> :followings, :source => :user
```

in which a User (as in an instance of the user model) has_many :followers, which are really just other users. So a user has_many users. This seems very weird to me that a User has_many :users, as if something should break when you write that, so I thought doign has_many :followers ...:source => :user might be meant to stop things from breaking.

According to one answer on this SO question [Need help to understand :source option of has_one/has_many through of Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632408/need-help-to-understand-source-option-of-has-one-has-many-through-of-rails), which was about the :source method for has_many associations, one rationale for using :source is to take code that looks this

```
class Newsletter
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, :through => :subscriptions
end
```

and change it into this

```
  class Newsletter
    has_many :subscriptions
    has_many :subscribers, :through => :subscriptions, :source => :user
   end
```

so that instead of doing this

```
  Newsletter.find(id).users
```

one would do the much more logical (because Newsletters have subscribers not users)

```
   Newsletter.find(id).subscribers
```

So, returning to the code from the book, my question is, is the only rationale for doing this in the User model

```
 has_many :followers, :through -> :followings, :source => :user
```

to make more readable code `User.find(id).followers` ? There would otherwise be no problem doing

```
User.rb 

has_many :users
```

Because if Rails let you do that (i.e. it doesn't break the application), then where would you put the belongs_to?

```
User.rb
has_many :users
belongs_to :user
```

This would seem very weird to me, but if :source is only there to let you write clearer queries, then this code should still work?

Update: the point of the question is, is there anything stopping anyone from doing this?

```
 User.rb
    has_many :users
    belongs_to :user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct you don't need the source, its because you are removing the through parameter

User doesn't have may users

User has many following, each of which have a user so you need:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :followings
  has_many :users, :through => :followings
end
```

See more here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Comment: I know Users doesn't have many :users, but the point of the post is, could it? It seems totally illogical to say User has_many :users, belongs_to :user.

Comment: This is a self referential association, and is perfectly acceptable, they are often renamed to make them more logical because as you say when does a users user really mean? For example rather than a `belongs_to :user`, and `has_many: :users` you'd do something like `belongs_to :father, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'father_id'`, and `has_many :children, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'father_id'`