# Can't create alias name for has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my Migration code:

1.User

```
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :password
      t.string  :department

      t.timestamps
    end
```

2.Ploy

```
    create_table :ploys do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :state
      t.string :description
      t.string :location
      t.float  :spend

      t.references :creator, index: true, class_name: "User"

      t.timestamps
    end
```

3.participants

```
   def change
    create_table :participants do |t|
      t.belongs_to :ploy
      t.belongs_to :user

      t.timestamps
    end
```

This is my Model code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :create_ploys, class_name: "Ploy"

  has_many :participants
  has_many :ploys, through: :participants, source: :join_ploys
end

class Ploy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User"

  has_many :participants
  has_many :users, through: :participants, source: "joiners"
end

class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :ploy
end
```

When i call user.join_ploys, but give me a error: **NoMethodError: undefined method `join_ploys'**

So i think maybe something is wrong about :source, But i don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so where are you defining a model or association for joiners and join_ploys? You can't just create a :source without defining what it is. Check out this SO: [Need help to understand :source option of has_one/has_many through of Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632408/need-help-to-understand-source-option-of-has-one-has-many-through-of-rails)