# Querying through a self join reference in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many-through

I have a model of `users` and `things`

Users can have one `leader` and many `followers` which are other users. User can also have `things`

So I have these definitions which use a self join relationship:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :things, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :followers, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'leader_id'
    belongs_to :leader, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'leader_id'
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

So I can query ask for a list of `things` that a `user` has by asking, for example `User.first.things`. I can also get a list of `followers` of a `user` with `User.first.followers`.

How do I get a list of things that a user's followers have. I think I might need to use a `has_many through` relationship but I can't seem to figure it out as I'm not sure how to deal with the fact that a `Leader` can have `things` through a 'follower' but also directly themselves

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def all_things
  Thing.where(:user_id => followers.map(&:id).push(id))
end
```

It returns a `scope` so you should be able to continue the chain, for example:

```
User.first.all_things.visible
```

#### Update

If you are only interested in the *followers' things* without adding the *user's things* to the batch it is better is you do it directly with a `has_many through`:

```
has_many :followers_things, :through => :followers, :source => :things
```

Check [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632408/need-help-to-understand-source-option-of-has-one-has-many-through-of-rails)

Comment: Just beware this solution is not following an infinite recursion among all the levels of `leadership`. Meaning that this solution is not having in consideration that a `follower` can also be a `leader` for other `users` and so also having inherited `things`.

Comment: This is on the right track. At the moment it returns (as the name suggests) all the things which a `user` has and which their `followers` have. I just want things their `followers` have. But I should be able to figure it from here

Comment: Got it, just drop the `.push(id)` so: `Thing.where(:user_id => followers.map(&:id))' worked for what I needed

Comment: I was confused by the part of your description that says: _a Leader can have things through a 'follower' but also directly themselves_

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
all_things = (your_user.followers.each { |f| f.things }).flatten
```

This should return an array containing `things` that belong to all `your_user`'s followers.