# Rails 5.1: retrieve records for nested association with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm trying to implement [includes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) in `has_many` / `belongs_to` association similar to this example:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books, -> { includes :line_items }
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
end
```

At the moment when I do `@author.books` I see in my console it loads `Book` and `LineItem` and shows records of `Book`, no records for `LineItem`. I get undefined method error when I try `@author.books.line_items`. Nor does `@author.line_items` work.

How do I get `LineItem` records for `Author`, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to add a `has_many` association to `Author`.

Like this: `has_many :line_items, through: :books, source: :line_items`.

Then if you do `author.line_items`, then you wil get the `LineItem` records for the Author.

The way you are using the [includes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) method, allows you to access the `line_items` through the books. 
Something like this: `author.books.first.line_items`, this code will not go to the database because the `includes` you have in `has_many :books, -> { includes :line_items }` autoloaded the `line_items`

Comment: the `source` option is optional in this case (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632408/need-help-to-understand-source-option-of-has-one-has-many-through-of-rails)

Comment: Thank you, this is nice :) Works like charm! For me it seemed to work when I changed to `source: :line_items` - like plural. Maybe typo there.

Comment: @matiss yes it is a typo! Edited!