# Select the favorite groups

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have a model favorit_group (user:references, group:references).

And would like to find all the favorites groups of my User with something like that :

```
current_user.fav_groups
```

I suppose that i have to write something like this in my model User, but it's not working

```
has_many :favorit_groups, dependent: :destroy
has_many :fav_groups, through: :favorit_groups, class_name: "Group"
```

Is anyone who is working with this kind of association ? Or should I have to join and merge the model favorit_groups inside my User model ?

Comment: Take a look at the `source` option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632408/understanding-source-option-of-has-one-has-many-through-of-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the relation name `fav_groups` is not the same as the relation name between `FavoritGroup` and `Group`, Rails does not not how to fetch those records.

Luckily, `has_many` accept a `source` option:

```
has_many :fav_groups, source: :group, through: :favorit_groups, class_name: "Group"
```

See full explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails

Comment: My mistake, I did'nt edit my question but I have also try with 'group'

Comment: Could not find the source association(s) "fav_group" or :fav_groups in model FavoritGroup

Comment: I'm already using the user.groups association, and I would like to buid something similar for the favorites groups

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling fav_group/fav_groups somewhere else on a FavoritGroup object by mistake? This part you described us seems correct

Comment: I don't think so, So if I understand you well, something like : has_many :favorit_groups, dependent: :destroy          
  has_many :fav_groups, through: :favorit_groups, class_name: "Group"  Should be correct ?

Comment: You are missing the `source: :group` option (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632408/understanding-source-option-of-has-one-has-many-through-of-rails)

Comment: After the class name ?

Answer (score 0):

Its look like there is many to many relationship between `user` and `group`

```
class User

  has_many :favorit_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :fav_groups, through: :favorit_groups, source: :group

end
```

Try
`current_user.groups` which will automatical fire a join query and fetch those groups that are marked favorite by the use i.e those groups for which an entry is present in `favorit_groups` table

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need the association current_user.groups for other stuff, so I would like to build a new one with a scope .fav_groups