# Rails Many to Many with Extra Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

So I have these tables:

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :username
  t.string :email
  t.string :password_digest

  t.timestamps
end

create_table :rooms do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.string :password
  t.integer :size
  t.integer :current_size

  t.timestamps
end

create_table :rooms_users do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user, index: true
  t.belongs_to :room, index: true

  t.boolean :is_admin

  t.timestamps
end
```

I made it so, when I call Room.find(1).users I get a list of all the users in the room. However, I also want to be able to call something like Room.find(1).admins and get a list of users that are admins (where is_admin in rooms_users is true). How would I do that?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What have you tried? What worked? What didn't work?

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `has_many through:` instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many`. Both define many to many associations but `has_many through:` uses a model for the join rows.

The lack of a model makes `has_and_belongs_to_many` very limited. You cannot query the join table directly or add additional columns since the rows are created indirectly.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_rooms
  has_many :rooms, through: :user_rooms
end

class Room < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_rooms
  has_many :users, through: :user_rooms
end

class UserRoom < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :room
end
```

You can use your existing schema but you need to rename the table `users_rooms` to `user_rooms` with a [migration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) - otherwise rails will deride the class name as `Rooms::User`.

```
class RenameUsersRooms < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    rename_table(:users_rooms, :user_rooms)
  end
end
```

> However, I also want to be able to call something like
>   Room.find(1).admins and get a list of users that are admins (where
>   is_admin in rooms_users is true). How would I do that?

You want to use a left inner join:

```
User.joins(:user_rooms)
    .where(user_rooms: { room_id: 1, is_admin: true })
```

To roll that into the class you can setup an association with a scope applied:

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_rooms
  has_many :users, through: :user_rooms
  has_many :user_room_admins, class_name: 'UserRoom', ->{ where(is_admin: true) } 
  has_many :user_room_admins, through: :user_rooms, 
    class_name: 'User',
    source: :user
end
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot (or should not) define two relations with the same name on the same object. Also, I think having `users_rooms` or `rooms_users` as a table name won't change the way Rails will deride the class. It will just call `camelize`. Otherwise a basic `has_many :relation_with_underscore` would be resolved to `Relation::With::Underscore`

Comment: No the naming actually matters. If you have plural ”things_something” rails will look for Things::Something. While the singular ‘thing_’ is not treated as a namespace. It’s a very common issue. It’s also why you can nest models without setting table_name.

Comment: You can declare two associations with the same name but the later will overwrite all the methods that the previous declaration created.

Comment: You are right about the pluralized name and how Rails resolve the constant name, I am surprised as I have several `has_many` relations having a pluralized part in the name and without a class_name option but I don't get any constant error. Is that a Rails 5 feature? I tested it with Rails 5 only

Comment: No Im pretty sure the behavior was the same in Rails 4

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `proc` in the `has_many` relation to set SQL clauses, like `ORDER` or `WHERE`:

```
# room.rb
has_many :rooms_users, class_name: 'RoomsUser'
has_many :users, through: :rooms_users
has_many :admins, 
  proc { where(rooms_users: { is_admin: true }) },
  through: :rooms_users,
  class_name: 'User',
  source: :users

# user.rb
has_many :administrated_rooms,
  proc { where(rooms_users: { is_admin: true }) },
  through: :rooms_users,
  class_name: 'Room',
  source: :rooms
```

You can simplify this with a simple `scope` defined in the `RoomsUser` model, something like:

```
# rooms_user.rb
scope :as_admins, -> { where(is_admin: true) }
```

And use it in the proc:

```
# user.rb
has_many :administrated_rooms,
  proc { as_admins },
  through: :rooms_users,
  class_name: 'Room',
  source: :rooms
```

---

`source` option explained:

> With `source: :users`, we're telling Rails to use an association called `:users` on the RoomsUser model (as that's the model used for `:rooms_users`).

(from [Understanding :source option of has_one/has_many through of Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632408/understanding-source-option-of-has-one-has-many-through-of-rails))

Comment: I did something similar and am still getting this error: ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "admin" or :admins
in model RoomsUsers. Try 'has_many :admins, :through => :rooms_users, :source => <name>'. Is it one of user or room?

Comment: @КрисиСтоянов I updated my answer. The `source` option is necessary for `has_many through` when the argument to the `has_many` is not the same name as the relation from the join record to the "end record". If you tell rails `Room has_many :users, through: :rooms_users`, it will guess that `RoomsUser` has a relation `has_many :users`. In your case, the `has_many` name is not the same so you have to tell rails which `source` relation it has to use to find the records.

Comment: Using the table name `rooms_users` will cause a missing constant error since rails will attempt to load `Rooms::User`. You either need to rename the table or set `self.table_name = 'rooms_users'`. The former is preferable.

Comment: Oh yeah, my answer was implying that the relation is an `has_many through` and not HABTM (which I thought was already the case since the join table has an extra field + timestamps and those are not included in a regular HABTM if I remember correctly).