# Rails: How to create a has_many through association with an alias/class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to transform my HABTM to has_many through relations. Sometimes I have to connect the same models in different ways. For example to specify different roles for authors.

With a HABTM I would do this through the declaration of a class_name option. Just like:-

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :curators, :class_name => :author, :through => :projects_curators
end

class ProjectsCurator < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :project_id, :author_id
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :author
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :projects, :through => :projects_curators
end
```

But when I transform everything into a has_many through:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_curators
  has_many :curators, :class_name => :author, :through => :project_curators
end

class ProjectCurator < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :project_id, :author_id
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :author
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_curators
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_curators
end
```

I get: `Could not find the source association(s) :curator or :curators in model ProjectCurator. Try 'has_many :curators, :through => :project_curators, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :author or :project?`

When I add `:source`

```
has_many :curators, :class_name => :author, :through => :project_curators, :source => :author
```

I get:

```
uninitialized constant Project::author
```

How can I get this working? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: First off try class_name: 'Author'.  The class_name needs to be a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Understanding :source option of has_one/has_many through of Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632408/understanding-source-option-of-has-one-has-many-through-of-rails) should help you out

When you declare the source you're not declaring the class of the has_many relationship, but the name of the relationship you're using as the middle man. In your case, try:

```
has_many :curators, :through => :project_curators, :source => :author
```

As someone in the above post states:

> Most simple answer - the name of the relationship in the middle

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mark. Great reference. I had to use `has_many :curators, :through => :project_curators, :source => :author`, but had `alias_attribute :curator` in author.rb, which exists only in Rails 4+ and collided with all the rest. No need for :class_name apparently. Could you edit your answer?

Comment: I should have read more carefully :) Edited and glad it's working